# Ethernet will not activate on DELL/Alienware Aurora R4 box running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: networking, ethernet, ubuntu-14.04

I'm running an Alienware Aurora R4 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the Ethernet cable is plugged in, the light is amber, but it will not connect.  It shows: NEVER USED.

I've turned off IPV6 and set IPV4 connection to AUTO DHCP

The Device MAC Address is empty, since what was there didn't change anything and CLONED MAC Address is empty as well.

MTU = Automatic

Any thoughts on this?

So I just need to get the Ethernet working and that's it. Wireless is fine but sometimes SLOW on bring up websites although my download speed is 67MBps - 85MBps

Comment: Could you incorporate the output of `sudo lshw -c network` and also `ifconfig` in your post body?